# How to match a file which starts with alphanumeric characters and has only three of these special characters . _ -?

Tags: regex, perl

I am a beginner in perl and wanted to match files that start with A-Z and 0-9. They also contain only `. _ -` special characters.
This is what I have so far:

```
if (($file !~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9][\-\_\.a-zA-Z0-9]*/)) {
    print ("error: invalid filename");
}
```

I tested the program and it can find file name errors like -5, $5, #5,
but it cannot catch file names with errors like 5#, 5%, 5@ etc…

I couldn't find out the real issue at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're missing a final `$` to make this a full-string match. Without it, you're allowing any symbols after the optional group `[\-\_\.a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your regex is anchored at the beginning (`^`), but not at the end. Any `$file` that *starts with* a valid filename is accepted. Since `5#` starts with `5`, it goes through.

Fix:

```
if ($file !~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9][\-_.a-zA-Z0-9]*\z/) {
    print "error: invalid filename\n";
}
```

`\z` matches only at the end of the string, anchoring the pattern at the end.

`_` is not a regex metacharacter and does not need to be escaped. `.` is not a metacharacter in a `[` `]` group.